# Spyder can't load tensorflow in conda environment although python can

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I created a conda environment including `Spyder` and `tensorflow` in the dependencies and all installs went without errors.

When I activate the environment and launch python, I can import tensorflow and run code without any issues.

**However** when launching spyder from within the environment (Spyder shows on the bottom of the GUI that is part of that conda environment), and load tensorflow, it throws an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
```

and from then the Console gets stuck repeating the same error.

Why does spyder have issues importing a module that python in the same environment can import?  How can I fix this?

I have tried re-installing spyder in the conda environment but the same issue prevails.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall tensorflow-estimator `pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator` and uninstall Tensorflow.

```
#After fresh installing tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
#Install tensorflow_estimator
pip install -U tensorflow_estimator
```

Try [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23163#issuecomment-509178978) workaround as well.